# How to show uninstalled package size in Debian

Tags: linux, debian, apt

Is there a way to show the package size without installing a package in Debian, using apt-get,dpkg or something similar (please don't say install YUM)?

Comment: Are you asking how to find the size of the `.deb` files before they are downloaded installed?  Or asking how much space (after decompression) the package will consume on your system.

Comment: space on disk/installed space.  Tristan's answer seems to cover both so I accepted it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use apt-cache:

```
root@b:~# apt-cache show sl | grep Size
Installed-Size: 120
Size: 26680
```